# How to rename file by matching filename to substring of name in textfile

Tags: linux, bash, unix, text, rename

I have a directory with 300 files that look like this:

```
S221_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz   S30_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz    
S95_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz    S159_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz   
S222_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz   S31_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz    
S96_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
G1F0Blank3_S184_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
G1F0Blank3_S184_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
G1F0C1A_S101_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
G1F0C1A_S101_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
G1F0C1B_S154_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
G1F0C1B_S154_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I would like to add the string in front of the filename in the text file to the matching file in my directory. There is one entry in the text file for each file in my directory. I would most like to be able to do this in my unix terminal.

Thank you!

Comment: you basically want to rename the files in your directory to the matching names in the text file?

Answer (score 0):

```
   # first, list all files:
   ls *.gz | while read FILENAME
   do
       # then, get the new filename from the file
       # replace filenames.txt with your TXT file
       NEW_FILENAME=$( grep "$FILENAME" /path/to/filenames.txt )
       # and finally, rename everything
       [ "$NEW_FILENAME" != "" ] && mv "$FILENAME" "$NEW_FILENAME" -v
   done
```

In case of doubt, backup everything before

Answer (score 0):

```
for var in *                                                                                                                                                                        
do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
newFileName=`grep -i $var /path/to/newNamefile`                                                                                                                                                 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]                                                                                                                                                                     
then                                                                                                                                                                                
mv $var $newFileName                                                                                                                                                                
fi                                                                                                                                                                                  
done
```