# Rename catalog names with a reformatted name, bash/cli

Tags: recursion, rename, reformatting

Exporting a few thousand photos from my iPhone using the iMazing app on MacOS give me a set of catalogs:

```
2020-04-27
2020-04-28
Stockholm - 2020-04-29
Nacka - 2020-04-30
```

Some catalogs have a placename in front of the date. I want to rename the catalogs to this format, placename trailing date, preferable using a script/cli:

```
2020-04-27
2020-04-28
2020-04-29-Stockholm
2020-04-30-Nacka
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006606/how-to-rename-file-by-matching-filename-to-substring-of-name-in-textfile). I could easily create a file with the new filenames. However, I have tried in vain to make the script work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a small error in the script in the linked post. The last line should be:

```
[ "$NEW_FILENAME" != "" ] && mv -v "$FILENAME" "$NEW_FILENAME"
```

With that slight correction it works (at least on MacOS) just fine.